# Stringr regex for alpha including accents

Tags: r, regex, stringr

```
string = "2001 - l'odyssée de l'espace"
```

What the regex to extract only "l'odyssée de l'espace" with `str_exctract()`?

`str_extract_all(string, '[^-[:digit:]]')` would work, but a can't concat it back together.

Comment: `[^-[:digit:]]` might work (with `trimws` clean-up).

Comment: it returns a space with `str_extract()` and " " " " "l" "'" "o" "d" "y" "s" "s" "é" "e" " " "d" "e" " " "l" "'" "e" "s" "p" "a" "c" "e" with `str_extract_all()`

Comment: sorry, I was looking at starter regexes, that isn't what you need for `stringr::str_extract`

Comment: Use `sub("^\\d+\\s*-\\s*", "", string)`. The `trimws(gsub("[-[:digit:]]", "", string))` will remove `-` and digits anywhere in the part after the initial digits + spaces/hyphen (`stringr::str_extract_all(string, "[^-[:digit:]]+")` has the same problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a base R approach:

```r
trimws(gsub("[-[:digit:]]", "", string))
# [1] "l'odyssée de l'espace"
```

An imperfect `stringr` extraction:

```r
stringr::str_extract_all(string, "[^-[:digit:]]+")
# [[1]]
# [1] " "                      " l'odyssée de l'espace"
```

which can be extended with

```r
grep("\\S", stringr::str_extract_all(string, "[^-[:digit:]]+", simplify = TRUE), value = TRUE)
# [1] " l'odyssée de l'espace"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, to extract what is needed :

```
sub('\\d+\\s*-\\s*(.*)', '\\1', string)
#[1] "l'odyssée de l'espace"
```

Comment: That's some regex voodoo. Is there a helper to build those or you just have to know?

Comment: I guess it's more practice than anything.